How do Java's equality tests (`==`) work between same primitives (e.g. int, char) and what is most efficient?
How do Java's equality tests work between primitives?  I'm specifically looking for efficiency (and speed) within single-type comparisons.  Is the char == char comparison faster than int == int?
I know that behind the hood, chars are treated as numbers.  I'm having difficulty finding any explanations on how == truly functions with primitives (it understandably doesn't have a JavaDoc/Oracle page, and I can't find its source code).  The only data I found that can be tangentially related is that int uses 4 bytes, while char uses 2.  (I don't need the extra size; all the data I'm comparing would be a real-world character, and Unicode can be represented in Java's 2-byte char, unlike C's 1-byte for ASCII.)
Is the speed the same, or is char faster due to its smaller size?
I understand that the base code for its operations may be derived from C or even assembly.  If C (or equivalent) or higher, where would I be able to find it to further understand how it works?

BTW  int == int is the exact same bytecode created by the compiler as char == char (even the same as boolean == boolean or every integer that is not long)

Generally, you'll only have a performance penalty for comparing primitives when they're larger than your CPU's register size. On a 32-bit architecture, then, you can expect to compare a 4-byte type in one cycle; on a 64-bit architecture, you can expect to compare an 8-byte type in one cycle. This isn't specific to the JVM.

So from an efficiency perspective, you can expect there to be differences only when you're working in data in enough bulk to change frequency with which content is found in cache. (Yes, this matters even with the JVM in the way -- see https://hypirion.com/musings/persistent-vector-performance-summarised for an example going into how CPU caching makes a huge difference in the data types used as some of the major primitives in Clojure, a JVM-based LISP).

(BTW, it's not true that all of Unicode fits in two bytes per character; UTF-16 can store many characters in two bytes, but others use four; if you want a 100% firm guarantee that you can use simple math to go from character offset to byte offset, you need UTF-32).

And to add the last part of the question: If one of the two compared variables has a smaller register/bit/byte size, it will be cast into the higher format, so no matter how many bytes a char has (1-4), when compared to the int, it will always have 4 bytes. Java adjusts the sign bit automatically, and as there are no unsigned primitive numbers, you cannot get into trouble there. The only time that actually plays a role is when reading unsigned values from exchange streams, like files or sockets.

"I'm specifically looking for efficiency ..." - This is premature optimization.  And in this case, it is highly unlikely to pay off, since == for int, short, char and byte are typically all handled the same way both at the bytecode and native code / hardware level.  It could be significant for >arrays< of Java primitives ... but that's not what you asked about.

@StephenC The comparison is to test a single char against a char[] array to find its index.  I can't think of a better way than iterating over it with a for loop.  Converting the array to an Object type and using an indexof() is beyond wasteful.

Your code is probably running on 64 bits hardware. So it can compare two 8 byte long values just as fast as two 2 byte short values (I mention short on purpose; if for some reason you want numbers in 2 bytes, use it; don’t use char for numbers, it will confuse everyone).

@EliezerMeth - If you are asking this question about some specific use-case ... it would make more sense if you showed us the code.  (Rather than asking a general question about the efficiency of == ...)  The problem with a Q&A site is that we can only answer the questions that you ask.  Not the ones that you should have asked.

By the way, the char type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most characters. You should instead be using code point integer numbers, either int primitive or Integer object, when dealing with individual characters.


Is the speed the same, or is char faster due to its smaller size?

No. There are many reasons and they all say no.
The 'minor' primitives say: No.

How do primitives work

You have the 4 major primitives and the 4 minors. The majors are float, double, int, and long. These have bytecode for all relevant operations. For example, you have FADD, DADD, IADD, and LADD - for, respectively, 'add two floats', 'add two doubles', 'add two ints', and 'add two longs'.
The other 4 are the minors: char, boolean, short, and byte. These do not have any bytecode. Or, nearly no bytecode - there's bytecode to read/write to a byte/char/boolean/short array, but there is no BADD for 'add 2 bytes together'.
The minors are represented at the class file level and in the JVM with an int. Thus, trivially then,

is char faster due to its smaller size

No. Because it isn't smaller. It's 32 bits just the same. If anything, it is slower, because java has to emulate overflow for these things.
CPU design says: No.
CPUs have a size they are 'comfy' with. It's not that they cannot operate on other sizes. However, they are fastest at that size, or, at least, operations on smaller things are no faster than on the 'comfy' size. This is generally called a word. Also, often memory has to be aligned; any operation on memory is simply not allowed and would cause a CPU fault condition unless that operation is done on a position that is evenly divisible by the word size.
On 64-bit architecture, word size is 64-bits. That's... kinda the point: That's why 64-bit architecture is called that.
All of java's primitives are 64-bit or smaller, so, trivially, no, things aren't faster just because they are smaller.
In fact, due to alignment rules, generally everything is 64-bit anyway. Even a boolean. Arrays are an exception (a new byte[100] takes about 100 bytes of memory, not 800; but 100 separate fields of type byte may well take 800, it is up to a JVM implementation).
So how does it work?
Well, something like someChar == someChar results in bytecode you can investigate with the javap tool. And how does that end up running on a CPU? Who knows! That's the point of java. It's a spec, not a single implementation. How that ends up actually working depends on a combinatory explosion of factors - JVM version, JVM vendor (though, practically, that is irrelevant; all vendors operate on pretty much the same codebase these days), architecture (as in, what CPU you have - things are different on ARM chips than intel chips for example, even x86 vended by intel vs. AMD can make a difference!), OS, bit mode, flags like compressedOops, whether your code has been hotspotted, and more.
But, in practice? The CPU has an opcode for equality and that's likely what ends up being used. How does that work? Books on how CPUs work including treatises on microcode and such are available and hundreds of pages long requiring PhD level university degrees to understand. At some point asking 'but.. why?' ends up at 'well a really long time ago there was this big bang...'.
Some details from the spec
Note that java, like most languages, fundamentally does not support heterogenous operations. You simply cannot add a float and a double together, period. At least, at the class level. There's FADD (add 2 floats) and DADD (add 2 doubles). There is no FDADD or DFADD. So, when you write:
float x = 1.5;
double y = 2.5;
System.out.println(x + y);

That's not possible. However, javac makes that possible by silently adding a conversion - the bytecode generated here will first convert x to a double, and then adds the two doubles, and that's then passed to the println method. So why does javac get to just silently inject that conversion (which you can manually force with casts - System.out.println((double) x + y) is allowed, and would generate exactly the same bytecode?
Because the java spec says that if an operation is not possible, but applying a 'widening conversion' to one of the two parts of an operation would make it possible, javac will inject that conversion silently. widening conversions are:

byte, short, char can convert to int.
byte, short, char, and int can convert to long.
float can convert to double.
int and long can convert to float or double.

Note that casting is implied and automatic, even for narrowing conversion, when using the compound assignment operators. This is legal java:
float x = 5.5;
int y = 10;
y += x;

But this is a compiler error:
float x = 5.5;
int y = 10;
y = y + x;

Because the second one first converts y to a float, then adds 2 floats, then tries to assign this float to an int param which is a narrowing conversion and therefore isn't allowed and requires an explicit cast.

"And how does that end up running on a CPU? Who knows!" - It is possible to find out for a specific program running with specific JVM on specific hardware ... by getting the JVM to dump out the native code that the JIT compiler emits for a specific method.  But the point you are making is correct.
